# How to maintain one js file across several components of an application without any error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My web application has several components, lets say contacts, products, help which I can browse from my home page. Each such component is having various widgets for example dropdown, textarea, button etc. For all these I am having only one js file across all the `components/tabs`. However, if a currently opened `component/tab` is not having a particular item (say dropdown) which is mentioned in the js , it throws error like below

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

How can I ensure using one single js file that when a tab is opened only the
`widgets/items` present in that tab should be considered, not other widgets. My js file looks like below which has one `$(document).ready(function() { construct`, inside which it has all the code for the event driven behavior of the page :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tab_1_dropdown").on('change', function(e) {
            // something
      });

       $('#tab_2textarea').click(function(e) {
           // something
       });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misinterpreted the problem.

If it was because the element with the id `tab_1_dropdown` was missing, then this code would run and you would apply your change event handler to all zero matching items (and there would be no error).

The error message says that `$().on` is not defined. That would imply that your script depends on jQuery and you have included an ancient version that doesn't include that feature.

You can test to see if `$().on` is available before you try to use it.

```
var $tab1 = $("#tab_1_dropdown")
if ($tab1.on) { /* etc etc */ }
```

It would be better to fix your system so it *consistently* included a modern version of jQuery though.